# using jquery validate plugin in asp.net controls not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, web-parts

I am trying to use the jquery plugin `validate()` method to validate a div in my current sharepoint visual webpart. 
I am not sure why this is not working. it does nothing at all.

Here is the code.

```
     <div id="main" runat="server">
            <h3>2. Select your study subject.<span class="red">*</span></h3>                            
                        <asp:RadioButtonList CssClass="required" ID="rdb_study_popul" runat="server"  OnSelectedIndexChanged="rdb_study_popul_SelectedIndexChanged">
                            <asp:ListItem>Individuals</asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem>Population</asp:ListItem>
                        </asp:RadioButtonList>
        </div>

           <asp:Button ID="btn_studysubject_section"   runat="server" CssClass="WBSButtonhide" OnClick="btn_studysubject_section_Click"
                        Text="Next"/>
```

here is the jquery

```
      $("input[type='submit']").click(function () {
         if ($(this).val() != 'Back') {
             var names = [];
             var info = " ";
            $('#<%= main.ClientID %>').validate({
           rules:
                  {                  
                  <%= rdb_study_popul.ClientID%> : { required: true }
                   },             
           messages:
                  {
                   <%= rdb_study_popul.ClientID%> : "This field cannot be empty, please enter between"
                  }
             });

         }
     });
```

Answer (score 1):

It's not working because you are referencing an object that does not exist on your page.  Since you have `runat="server"` on your div tag, the `Id` of that tag is NOT "main".

```
<div id="main" runat="server">
```

You need to do this in your jQuery:

```
$('#<%= main.ClientID %>').validate({....
```

Comment: edited but still it does not work. with in the validate function it says incorrect syntax missing a { i am not sure where it is

Comment: When I add jquery events to asp.net server controls I find it's a lot easier to just add a class to the control that you can hook onto. I would add a class named something like jqMainDiv (signifying it's only being used as a jquery hook) and then use that as your selector. I would do the same for the two other IDs you are referenceing.

Comment: appreciate your thought i am a novice in jquery can you show me how to write the rules if there is a css class attached. i have no idea....